# @PostFilter on a wrapped list?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In Spring Security, is it possible to apply @PostFilter to a method that doesn't return a list but a wrapped list, for instance `ResponseEntity<List<String>>` ?

I mean

```
@PostFilter("filterObject != DISCARD_STR")
ResponseEntity<List<String>> getStringList();
```

Will not work, will it ? Because the method don't return a list so filtered object can't be bind to the list elements.

Is there a solution to filter the inner list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can do it by using @PostAuthorize and editing the object.

```
@PostAuthorize("@myService.filter(returnObject.getBody())")
ResponseEntity<List<String>> getStringList();
```

MyService.java :

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    public boolean filter(List<String> list) {
        list.remove(DISCARD_STR)
    }

}
```